# Google Maps Embed API - Directions Mode - Optimized route with multiple waypoints

Tags: google-maps-embed

Do you know if there is a way to use the Google Maps Embed API with "Directions" mode to get the route between an origin/destination with multiple waypoints but **optimized**?

I know the Directions API can be used to retrieve a JSON or XML with optimized directions by specifying optimize=true parameter in the URL and I want to do the same with the Embed API directions mode.

Thanks!